Manga in which the main character fights horned demons/monsters with a weapon that transforms
I remember reading a manga as a kid where the main character had a weapon that transformed into four or five others and killed these horned demons or monsters.
I remember that in the beginning, four or five major heroes sacrificed themselves for him; his weapon was able to transform into all of theirs. I also remember the main hero guy having an arrow tattoo on his forearm that he "activates" to fight off a monster, but he gets turned into light by this.
I also remember there being some sort of monster fighting guild, and the monster fighters getting some sort of mark to indicate how strong they are, claiming bounties, and all that.
The last thing I remember is that one of the major enemies gets his horn cut off, which causes him to explode.
This was all a long time ago, but if anyone knows it, I’d be super thankful to find out what it was.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white and in roughly which year did you read it? Also, what forms did the weapon take?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

It was black and white as far as I remember. The only weapon I remember clearly is a massive axe that was usually too unwieldy.

I think it is Beet the Vandel Buster.

The Vandel Busters are a roving band of certified monster destroyers. Beet's biggest ambition in life is to become a Buster, but what can you say about a monster hunter who can barely stand the pain when he receives the mystical brand of a "Level 1 Vandel Buster"?Still, Beet is ready for action, and when a nearby town is invaded by deons, he rushes to help--without a clue as to how to trounce even a single member of the rampaging horde. But not knowing how formidable the Vandels are might work to his advantage because he doesn't know enough to be scared! Beet is about to learn that being a hero mayy be more than he bargained for...


Could you edit this to explain how Beet the Vandel Buster matches the manga described by the OP? It'd help other users decide how likely it is to be the correct answer.
